# Connecting to my session locale session from remote

Tags: ssh, vnc, rdp

I'm trying to find the best alternative to use my machine from local and remote "sharing" the same running application (I guess you could say the same x session, but I've not fully grasped yet how graphical sessions work and I guess there is also some way to move the same graphical application between x session).

Here are some use cases which I'm trying to address
Resume work remotely:

- I start a program locally
- I logout (the program keeps running)
- I connect from remote and see the same running program
  Resume work locally:
- I start a program remotely
- I logout (the program keeps running)
- I connect locally and see the same running program

I've seen that using x0vncserver I can control the local display, however this solution let me see all my screen on my local machine on my tiny laptop, which is kind of a mess.
Is there any better alternative?

p.s. I've already an ssh connection and I'll use port forwarding to make sure that the traffic is encrypted and secure

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about an X windows session, look into [`x11vnc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11vnc) which exports running X session via the VNC protocol. You can connect to it remotely with any [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) client, possibly also through a SSH tunnel, although it should support SSL/TLS connection of it's own.